# Determinant of matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be the matrix described when $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that:
[image]

Iv'e tried to factor out $a+b$, but got nowhere.

A hint or a solution would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let denote the given determinant $\Delta_n$ so by developing it along the first column we have
$$\Delta_n=(a+b)\Delta_{n-1}- \left|\begin{array}[ccccc]\\ab&0&\cdots&0\\
1&a+b&\cdots&0\\
0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&&\vdots
\end{array}\right|$$
and by developing the last determinant along the first line we find
$$\Delta_n=(a+b)\Delta_{n-1}-ab\Delta_{n-2}$$
Now solve this recursive equation knowing that $\Delta_1=a+b$ and $\Delta_2=a^2+b^2+ab$ to find the desired result.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: صباح الخیر Sami. Hope you have a very great day. :+)

Comment: Indeed, a great answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

Given that you know what you want to show, use induction and make use of the fact that:
$$(a+b)(a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}) -a^{n+1}b + ab^{n+1} = a^{n+2} - b^{n+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to compute this determinant is to show that it vanishes when $a/b = \omega,$ where $\omega$ is some $n+1$st root of unity (not $1,$ however). for this just substitute $a = \omega b,$ and start subtracting the last row/column.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily show that it works for 2x2 matrices. Then, as far as i can see you can simply proceed by induction where you calculate the (n+1)'st determinant by expanding by row.