# Fidning determinant in hot summer day

Tags: matrices, determinant

Find determinant of matrix A
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b & ab & 0 & ... & 0\\
1 & a+b & ab & ... & 0\\
0 & 1 & a+b & ... & 0\\
... & ... &... & ... &...\\
0 & 0 & 0 &... & a+b
\end{bmatrix}

Let's say shape is $N\times N$.
It seems $(a+b)\cdot row_{i} -  row_{i+1}$ for i from 1 up to N-1
So in case $a+b \neq 0$ and $n>1$ we have: $det(A) = \frac{((a+b)^2 - ab)^{n-1}}{(a+b)^{n-1}}\cdot(a+b) = \frac{(a^2 + ab + b^2)^{n-1}}{(a+b)^{n-1}}\cdot(a+b)$
Where is a mistake? I don't get right result in case $n>2$ ...
Thank you

Comment: Alright, I don't get the hot summer day...

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597256/42969

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!